# IDLE in virtualenv does not function correctly?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I installed numpy and other packages in virutalenv vpy1. I can correct import those packages if I invoke python command in console after activated the vpy1.

However, if I use IDLE, it cannot import those packages:

```
>>> import numpy

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

I then found out the IDLE does not have correct virtualenv setting. If I invoke python in console, the setting will be like this:

```
(vpy1)xxx ~ $ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun  1 2014, 03:20:25) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.real_prefix
'/home/xxx/python-2.7.6'
>>> sys.executable
'/home/xxx/virtualenvs/vpy1/bin/python'
```

if I use IDLE:

```
(vpy1)xxx ~ $ which idle
/home/xxx/virtualenvs/vpy1/bin/idle
(vpy1)xxx ~ $ idle
#in IDLE
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun  1 2014, 03:20:25) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'/home/xxx/python-2.7.6/bin/python2.7'
>>> hasattr(sys,'real_prefix')
False
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this problem. In the vpy1/bin the idle is directly link to `/home/xxx/python-2.7.6/bin/idle`, which using a wrong shebang. Change the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/env python` solve this problem.